# Immutable.js without redux, how do I create new lists without explicitly naming them?

Tags: immutable.js

**---Background---**
I'm trying to learn current best data management practices and as far as I can tell that means **stateless** / **stateful** **components** and **immutable data structure**. I'm having problems with implementing latter (immutables). I'm trying to incorporate it into angular 2 without redux. Redux is on my list of things to learn but for now I want to use immutable.js without redux.

**---The problem---**
How do I create a copy of an array in a service and return it on demand? I have this example code (just for **illustration** purposes, I haven't tested it!):

```
import { Product } from './product';
import { Immutable } from './immutable';

export class ProductListService {
    let id = 0;

    const cheese  = new Product(id++, 'cheese');
    const ham  = new Product(id++, 'ham');
    const milk = new Product(id++, 'milk');

    // I fill the list with some sample data
    let oldProductList = Immutable.List.of(cheese, ham, milk);
    let newProductList = [];
    let returnProductList = oldProductList;

    getProductList() {
        return returnProductList;
    }

    addProduct() {
        // As far as I know, this creates a deep immutable copy
        newProductList = oldProductList.withMutations(function (list) {
            list.push(new Product(id++, 'name'););
        });
        returnProductList = newProductList;
        oldProductList = newProductList;
    }
}
```

The above code is based on the example from the official docs where they just add a number to the variable each time they create a copy (I understand that is only for example purposes?). How do I go about creating new lists without using numbers? Do I use oldList / newList? Do I dynamically create new numbers for new variables so that I have a history of objects?

I feel I'm doing something wrong on a architectural level here. What is the correct approach? All immutable.js examples are using redux or show no real-life example, does someone know of a good material to learn about immutalbe.js (+ possible ng2?)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i fully understand what you want to do here,
but consider this:if you just want to push one element to the list you should not use `withMutations`.

```
let list1 = Immutable.List(['one'])
let list2 = list1.push('two')
console.log(list1.toJS()) // ['one']
console.log(list2.toJS()) // ['one', 'two']
```

Applying a mutation to create a new immutable object results in some overhead, which can add up to a minor performance penalty. use `withMutations` only If you need to apply a series of mutations locally before returning

```
let list1 = Immutable.List(['one'])
var list2 = list1.withMutations(function (list) {
  list.push('two').push('three').push('four').push('five');
});
console.log(list1.toJS()) //["one"]
console.log(list2.toJS()) //["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
```

here we create a temporary mutable (transient) copy of list 1 and apply a batch of mutations in a performant manner by using withMutations

I hope that answers your question

Comment: Hej, what I want is to avoid having to manually create list1, list2, list3, list4 etc. each time I create a new array. I mean, how do I know how many lists will I need?   
I'm reading more on this topic right now and it seems that creating an array with immutable.js does this automagically? So when I create an immutable var list and try to mutate it, it creates a new list with the same var name?

Comment: Exactly. Immutable data cannot be changed once created, instead it will always yields new updated data. new data are created using as much of the same structure as the original data as possible, reducing copying to a minimum to achieve space efficiency and acceptable performance.